# HTML5 Game Canvas - Calculate speed and direction for bullet using last velX and velY

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a game in HTML5 Canvas.
I'm trying to get the bullets shoot relative to the players velX and velY (vx and vy), here's the code, the problem is that its speed should be constant.

Here's the part where the problem comes:

```
if (keys[32]) {
    bullet.push({
        x: player.x,
        y: player.y,
        vx: player.vx * 10,
        vy: player.vy * 10,
    })
}
```

Here's the main code for the game:

```
<style>
.canvas {
border: 0px;
background-color: #FFF;
width: 1000px;
height: 500px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
</style>

<center>    
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
</center>

<script language="javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")


canvas.width = canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight
var w = canvas.width
var h = canvas.height

var player = {
x: w / 2,
y: h / 2,
s: 5,
vx: 0,
vy: 0,
}
var enemy = {
x: 0,
y: 0,
s: 4,
vx: 0,
vy: 0,
}

var bullet = []

var keys = []
var friction = 0.9

setInterval(draw, 1000/60)
function draw() {
canvas.width = canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight
w = canvas.width
h = canvas.height

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)

if (keys[40]) {
    if (player.vy < player.s) {
        player.vy++;
    }
}
if (keys[38]) {
    if (player.vy > -player.s) {
        player.vy--;
    }
}
if (keys[39]) {
    if (player.vx < player.s) {
        player.vx++;
    }
}
if (keys[37]) {
    if (player.vx > -player.s) {
        player.vx--;
    }
}
if (keys[32]) {
    bullet.push({
        x: player.x,
        y: player.y,
        vx: player.vx * 10,
        vy: player.vy * 10,
    })
}

for (i = 0; i < bullet.length; i++) {
    bullet[i].x += bullet[i].vx
    bullet[i].y += bullet[i].vy

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(bullet[i].x, bullet[i].y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
}

player.vx *= friction;
player.vy *= friction;
player.x += player.vx;
player.y += player.vy;


var dx = (enemy.x - player.x);
var dy = (enemy.y - player.y);
var mag = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
enemy.vx = (dx / mag) * -enemy.s,
enemy.vy = (dy / mag) * -enemy.s,
enemy.x += enemy.vx
enemy.y += enemy.vy

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
ctx.fillStyle = "black"
ctx.fill()
ctx.closePath()
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(enemy.x, enemy.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
ctx.fillStyle = "red"
ctx.fill()
ctx.closePath()
}
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: You want the speed to be 10 times more than the player's but head the same direction?

Comment: Yeah it is but the player's vx and vy changes all the time so the bullet speed isn't the same everytime tou shoot...

Comment: Ok, this is trigo, I'll edit my comment soon with more explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the speed to head the same direction as the player is moving you'd need to keep the proportions between the X and Y the same. Best to do this is through trigo.
The direction angle would be the tangent, because velocity is a vector

[image: Velocity as a vector sum]

```
var angle = Math.atan(Math.abs(vy/vx)) //Angle between Vx and the Velocity
```

then, you know the speed would be Vb,
so each axis would be calculated through trigo:

```
var vB = 1 //Speed of bullet
var vBx = vB*Math.cos(angle) //Speed of bullet on x-axis
if (vx<0) vBx*=-1; //Makes it the same direction
var vBy = vB*Math.sin(angle) //Speed of bullet on y-axis
if (vx<0) vBy*=-1; //Makes it the same direction
```

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WJKHD/

Comment: If you really want to, you should make the friction a subtraction, that's how it works in the real world. Also you could set a limit for the speed, but that's just a proposal.